# how to create KMZ file programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4.2

How can i create .KMZ (google earth file format) programmatically? .KMZ contains a .KML file (XML for location based data) and images in a directory named 'files', the KML and files directory compressed together makes KMZ.

Now the challenge here is to compress the files into a KMZ format. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate part of the documentation is https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives

The Apple KML example is very simplistic. If you want a fuller featured parser, I would recommend libKML. It has full support for the KML standard, and handles KML and KMZ files. The only catch is that it is written in C++, and uses intrusive pointers which can be a bit painful in Obj-C.

If you really want to write your own parser, and just need a way to unzip files, https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home should work for you.

Comment: I think the question was about _creating_ KML/KMZ files, not _parsing_ them.